# Outlook share same manager

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

I know that I've seen somewhere in Outlook that I've been able to view a list of other people that share the same manager as a given person.  It's useful for locating a peer of someone who's on vacation, etc.

I'm not able to find it currently.  I did a internet search and both Bing and Google seemed to think I was asking how to share my calendar.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In an e-mail, right click on the user's name and select Open Contact Card
- Select Organization
- An Org Tree should be displayed all the way up to the top

[image: Org Tree]

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  I see only the person listed on the organization tab.  I'm wondering if someone has turned off the feature.

Comment: You were right.  It turned out that Outlook was offline (had a red x displaying in it's icon on the Windows 7 task bar).  I restarted it and it appeared similar to your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Under calendar view, there are [calendar groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-view-or-delete-a-calendar-group-04fc64f2-b658-450b-8dce-dd27ed660570) in the left pane. There are typically arranged as

- My Calendar
- Shared Calendars
- Other Calendars

If your company already has them setup, you may see some additional calendars available. In my case, our company has one called **Team:** *{supervisor name}*. Under those we can see all our work associates.

You can also create these calendar groups. There is more information about it in the above link.